# Error en mi blockchain

Tags: python

Estoy creando una blockchain y me sale este error:

```
self.length = response.json(['length'])
TypeError: json() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

El código es este:

```
import datetime
import hashlib
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests
from uuid import uuid4
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class Blockchain:

def __init__(self):
    self.chain = []
    self.transactions = []        
    self.create_block(proof = 1, previous_hash = '0')        
    self.nodes = set()

def add_node(self,address):
    parsed_url = urlparse(address)
    self.nodes.add(parsed_url.netloc)
    
def replace_chain(self):
    network = self.nodes
    longest_chain = None
    max_length = len(self.chain)
    
    for node in network:
        response = requests.get(f'http://{node}/get_chain')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            length = response.json(['length'])
            chain = response.json(['chain'])
            
            if length > max_length and self.is_chain_valid(chain):                   
                max_length = length
                longest_chain = chain
                
        if longest_chain:
            self.chain = longest_chain
            return True
        return False
  

def create_block(self, proof, previous_hash):
    block = {'index': len(self.chain) + 1,
             'timestamp': str(datetime.datetime.now()),
             'proof': proof,
             'previous_hash': previous_hash,
             'transactions': self.transactions}
    self.transactions = []
    self.chain.append(block)
    return block

def add_transaction(self, sender, receiver, amount):
    self.transactions.append({'sender':sender,
                             'receiver':receiver,
                             'amount':amount})
    previous_block = self.get_previous_block()
    return previous_block['index']+1

def get_previous_block(self):
    return self.chain[-1]

def proof_of_work(self, previous_proof):
    new_proof = 1
    check_proof = False        
    while check_proof is False:
        hash_operation = hashlib.sha256(str(new_proof**2 - previous_proof**2).encode()).hexdigest()
        if hash_operation[:4] == '0000':
            check_proof = True
        else:
            new_proof += 1
    return new_proof
 
def hash(self, block):
    encoded_block = json.dumps(block, sort_keys = True).encode()
    return hashlib.sha256(encoded_block).hexdigest()

def is_chain_valid(self, chain):
    previous_block = chain[0]
    block_index = 1
    while block_index < len(chain):
        block = chain[block_index]
        if block['previous_hash'] != self.hash(previous_block):
            return False
        previous_proof = previous_block['proof']
        proof = block['proof']
        hash_operation = hashlib.sha256(str(proof**2 - previous_proof**2).encode()).hexdigest()
        if hash_operation[:4] != '0000':
            return False
        previous_block = block
        block_index += 1
    return True
    

app = Flask(__name__)

node_address = str(uuid4()).replace('-','')

blockchain = Blockchain()


@app.route('/mine_block', methods=['GET'])

def mine_block():
    previous_block = blockchain.get_previous_block()
    previous_proof = previous_block['proof']
    proof = blockchain.proof_of_work(previous_proof)
    previous_hash = blockchain.hash(previous_block)
    blockchain.add_transaction(sender = node_address, receiver = 'Pepito', amount=1)
    block = blockchain.create_block(proof,previous_hash)
    response = {'message':'Felicitats, has minat un bloc!',
                'index':block['index'],
                'timestamp':block['timestamp'],
                'proof':block['proof'],                
                'previous_hash':block['previous_hash'],
                'transactions':block['transactions']}
    return jsonify(response), 200


@app.route('/get_chain', methods=['GET'])
def get_chain():
    response = {'chain':blockchain.chain,
                'length':len(blockchain.chain)}
    return jsonify(response), 200


@app.route('/is_valid', methods=['GET'])
def is_valid():
    is_valid = blockchain.is_chain_valid(blockchain.chain)
    if is_valid:
        response = {'message':'La cadena funciona correctament!'}
    else:
        response = {'message': 'Alguna cosa no fuciona bé...'}
    return jsonify(response), 200
    

@app.route('/add_transaction', methods=['POST'])
def add_transaction():
    json = request.get_json()
    transaction_keys = ['sender', 'receiver', 'amount']
    if not all (key in json for key in transaction_keys):
        return 'Falta alguna part de la transacció.', 400
        
    index = blockchain.add_transaction(json['sender'], json['receiver'], json['amount'])
    response = {'message':f'La transacció serà afegida al bloc: {index}'}
    return jsonify(response), 201


@app.route('/connect_node', methods=['POST'])
def connect_node():
    json = request.get_json()
    nodes = json.get('nodes')
    if nodes is None:
        return "No hi ha nodes disponibles.", 401
    for node in nodes:
        blockchain.add_node(node)
    response = {'message': 'Tots els nodes estan conectats. La candena de blocs conté els següents nodes:',
                'total_nodes':list(blockchain.nodes)}
    return jsonify(response), 201

@app.route('/replace_chain', methods=['GET'])
def replace_chain():
    is_chain_replaced = blockchain.replace_chain()
    if is_chain_replaced:
        response = {'message':'Totes les cadenes dels nodes han sigut replaçades per la més llarga.',
                    'new_chain':blockchain.chain}
    else:
        response = {'message': 'Tot funciona perfectament, no cal actualitzar les cadenes.',
                    'actual_chain':blockchain.chain}
    return jsonify(response), 200


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5001')
```

Comment: `self.length = response.json()['length']`. La llamada a `json()` no lleva parámetros.

Comment: @CandidMoe No entiendo lo que dices. ¿Me podrías enseñar que cambiarias en el código? Gracias.

Comment: Ahi te lo escribi. `response.json()` devuelve un diccionario. El diccionario lo accesas con `['length']`.

Comment: @CandidMoe Vale no lo entendía ;) Tambien lo he cambiado en chain, pero ahora me sale otro error:`if length > max_length and self.is_chain_valid(chain):
NameError: name 'length' is not defined`

Comment: Es una pregunta por publicación.